# Nginx: How can I re-use this proxy pass config in multiple locations?

Tags: nginx

I have a location block like this:

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://mediacluster;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
```

Which passes requests to an upstream block. I am adding more complicated location blocks now, some of which I also want to pass to that upstream block. How can I achieve that without copying the proxy code over and over?

Can I set it up as an internal location and then reference that location somehow, or maybe I just need to place this is an external config file and include it in each area?

Answer (score 4):

You're already aware of [`include`](http://nginx.org/r/include). This is the way it's normally done, especially when you have to reuse the configuration in different `server`s.